# Run PHP File from cron job?

Tags: php, ssh, cron

Is it possible to set up a cron job that will execute a php script?

I have a php file and i want to run every 15 minutes using cron job.

My php file path: www.sitename.com/runcron.php

full path: /var/www/vhosts/sitename/httpdocs/runcron.php

I using centos server.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this line to your crontab, and make sure the location of `php` is correct (check it out with `which php`).

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/sitename/httpdocs/runcron.php
```

That's simple ;-)